# Prove that the cross $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:xy=0\}$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

Is this a valid proof? Just dabbling with some basic topology. Thanks.

$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:xy=0\}$

Let $G=\{(x,0):x\leq0\}$ and $H=\{(x,0):x\geq0\}$

Let $K=G \cup H = \mathbb{R} \text{ (open)}$

Let $G_1=\{(0,y):y\leq0\}$ and $H_1=\{(0,y):y\geq0\}$

Let $K_1=G_1 \cup H_1 = \mathbb{R} \text{ (open)}$

$K$ and $K_1$ are connected sets which are not separated since $K \cap K_1 = \text{{0}} \neq 0$.

Then $K \cup K_1$ is connected, $K$ and $K_1$ form a connection of $A$. Thus

$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:xy=0\}$ is connected.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Are you claiming that $K$ and $K_1$ are open subsets of $A$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Indeed, this is not true because there is a problem in $(0,0).$ But it does not matter for the actual proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you become more familiar with topology, you may also want to note that the cross is clearly path-connected as any point is connected by a straight line to the origin, and any path connected space is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a valid proof you are using the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are connected and $A\cap B$ is not empty, then $A\cup B$ is connected. This can be proved by considering a continuous function $f:A\cup B\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. Since $A$ is connected, we can asume, $f(A)=1$, this implies that $f(A\cap B)=1$, since $B$ is connected, $f(B)$ is contant and is $1$, so $f$ is constant.